# Еще раз о цитатах

Tags: цитата

Если в стихах используется восклицательная цитата, но в то же время она как бы включается в основное предложение, допустимо ли оставлять в ней заглавную букву и восклицательный знак?

Когда кризис бил снова и снова

И казалось, что «Дело – труба!»

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если цитата ***синтаксически связана с авторским текстом,*** **образуя придаточное предложение, то первое слово цитаты пишется, как правило, со строчной буквы, например:** Говоря о поэзии Пушкина, Н.А. Добролюбов писал, **что «в его стихах** впервые сказалась нам живая русская речь, впервые открылся нам действительный русский мир».

Что касается знаков препинания, то ваш пример подпадает под следующий пункт правила: 
Знак препинания не ставится:

> Если перед закрывающими цитату кавычками стоит **вопросительный или восклицательный знак,** а цитата не является **самостоятельным предложением и после всей фразы с цитатой должен был бы стоять вопросительный или восклицательный знак. Напр.:
>   **Лермонтов восклицает в предисловии, что это «старая и жалкая шутка!»**

Таким образом, правильно: Когда кризис бил снова и снова

И казалось, что ***«дело – труба!»***

См.: Справочник издателя и автора. А. Э. Мильчин, Л. К. Чельцова

Comment: Спасибо большое, Серж! И особенно за второй пункт.

Comment: Серж, а точку не надо после кавычек ставить? У Лопатина: Искандер заметил, что «мудрость — это ум, настоянный на совести...».  Здесь после многоточия и кавычек стоит точка.

Comment: Нет, там дальше предложение продолжается через запятую, я просто не все привела, т. к. меня интересовала именно пунктуация и орфография самой цитаты.

Comment: Sibylla, после восклицательного знака точка не ставится.